# Using If Modified Since in a caching proxy

Tags: c++, caching, proxy, httphandler

I'm writing a web caching proxy in C++ using CURL.

I developed the caching part, when my application downloads a file, it stores also it's last modification date, stores its MD5, to make the comparison later between last modification date (its MD5) in the response header and the one stored in my computer.

later I knew about the header If-Modified-Since, my question is can I rely on it in all the cases (all file types & sizes) ? using it will make my application faster ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently no. I tried to add this header to my fire fox http request, but the remote server responded like if the file has been changed (which is not true)